# How to calculate the sum of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n-4)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This sum: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}$$
can be calculated using this $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n=\frac{1}{1-a}$ ; $a<1$ cause we can calculate the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}$ and then calculate it's derivative.

Can we calculate this sum: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n-4)\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$
using a similar method?

If not, how can I calculate it?

Comment: Hint:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n x^n =\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: thank you so much! i got it.

Comment: @M.Noussa Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n-4)\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n-4\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$

then use

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n x^n =\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$